# Switch endpoint responses based on condition

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to have two endpoints with the same path and decide which one is enabled on startup.

To do so I've tried using `@ConditionalOnExpression()` but an error is thrown as it says a mapping already exists. One endpoint uses ModelAndView while the other provides a html string so I can't add an if statement in the body of the endpoint.

**Code**

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${my-property:false}")
@GetMapping(VIEW_INDEX)
public ModelAndView index(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ...
    return modelAndView;
}

@ConditionalOnProperty("${my-property}")
@GetMapping(VIEW_INDEX)
public String otherIndex(){
    return "/other/index";
}
```

**Error**

```
Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'controller' method 

There is already 'controller' bean method
```

How can I allow only one to be enabled based on a condition without there being an `Ambiguous mapping`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work if you try `@ConditionalOnProperty` or `ConditionalOnExpression` on 2 controllers with the same request mapping.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "my-property", havingValue = "true")
public class TestTrueController {

    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String index() {
        return "Forever true!";
    }
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "my-property", havingValue = "false")
public class TestFalseController {

    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String index() {
        return "Forever false!";
    }
}
```

If your `my-property` value is `true` it will print "Forever true!", if `false` it will print "Forever false!".

Comment: This was it thank you!